# Нужна ли запятая в предложении "Думаешь как удивить ребенка на День рождения?"

Tags: пунктуация

При проверке модератор ВК отклонил его, ссылаясь на то, что после слова "думаешь" нужна запятая.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запятая нужна, потому что это сложноподчиненное предложение. Главное предложение состоит из одного слова "думаешь". Запятая отделяет придаточное предложение. А "день рождения" пишется со строчной буквы. А еще, я бы предпочел "в" вместо "на".

**Думаешь, как удивить ребенка в день рождения?**

Сравните:

Пригласить друзей на день рождения.
Приготовить подарок ко дню рождения.

Comment: По поводу "в день рождения" и с маленькой буквы абсолютно согласен, но по-поводу запятой нет. Разве в данном предложении  "думаешь удивить" не будет являться двойным или составным сказуемым?

Comment: В вашем предложении есть "как", поэтому его смысл: А думаешь ли ты о том, как удивить ребенка в день рождения?. Здесь явно два предложения. Если убрать "как", то получим простое предложение с другим смыслом: Думаешь удивить ребенка в день рождения?